# Combination of two signals to determine the end signal sent through Simulink code

Tags: matlab, arduino, signals, simulink, logical-operators

#### Goal

I'm trying to have a second signal (caused by force applied to a sensor's surface area), once it reaches a set minimum, to determine a servo motor's position.  The motor's position is otherwise determined by a first signal (generated by EMGs that are measured with electrodes placed on a subject's body) that make give the servo preset positions when the signal crosses a certain threshold.

#### Schematic

[image: Simulink Work Flow]

I cannot seem to get the two signals to work together.  Any corrections and recommendations on how to make the logic within Simulink function as intended would be immensely appreciated.  I know little of the program and cannot find a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your diagram you go from numeric values (Sensors) to logical ones (>=301) back to numeric (*90) and again to logical (AND). What you are doing may be possible but hides the intention. First of all I would recommend you to clearly distinguish between logical conditions and values, similar to the following model. To help you with that you can turn on data-type display from Format > Port/signal display > Signal data types followed by an Update (Ctrl-D).

[image: first model]

Alternatively you could reduce the conditions as much as possible and operate only with values, such as

[image: second model]

However I do not fully understand your requirements and I'm also not sure what the input of the servo is representing (Speed, position, ...)? Maybe you could explain the desired behaviour a bit more detailed? In particular how do you come up with the limits (301, 300, ...).